# How to remove an element found in an array and shift the array elements to the left?

Tags: c

```
int search(int a[]) {

   int i,V,index;
   printf("Enter the element (V),That you want to find:>");
   scanf("%d",&V);

   for (i=0;i<N;i++) {
       if(a[i]==V) {
           V=a[i];
           index=i;
       }
   }
   printf("%d is located in a[%d].",V,index
)
```

Comment: What's `N`? Is that some global that's defined elsewhere? You haven't returned a value from your function either. What's the function supposed to find?

Comment: Yes, N is a macro equals 10 . Sorry for mistake. It is supposed to find an element which is V , and remove it then shift the elments to the left .

Comment: BTW- if the order's not important, you can replace the removed element with the last, it'll be much faster. Just mentioning :)

Comment: No, I want to remove the element and then shift the other elements to the left and add zero to the last one .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you do not care about the ordering of the elements you can delete the found element in O(1) time.

```
// Find the element you're looking for.
int index = find(A, V);

// Stuff the last element into the index found.
A[index] = A[N-1];

// Reduce the total number of elements.
N--;
```

Comment: Yeah. but I need to shift the elements to the left and put  zero at the end.

Comment: that's genius. exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 12):

If I needed to move everything down the array, I'd use `memmove()`, carefully.  And zap the vacated element with 0 or some other appropriate value.

```
if (index < N-1)
    memmove(&a[index], &a[index+1], ((N-1)-index) * sizeof(a[0]));
array[N-1] = 0;
```

Comment: Is  memove() function In C library ?

Comment: Yes: `memmove()` is in both C89 and C99, in `<string.h>`.  It is a variant of `memcpy()` which is safe to use when the areas to be copied overlap, as they do here.  It is not safe to use `memcpy()`.

Comment: Don't forget that the size parameter of `memmove()` is in bytes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you're missing the parenthesis in sizeof.

Comment: @pqsk: you're right; the parentheses aren't there, and it is extremely unusual for me to omit them.  However, I'm tolerably certain that they are not strictly necessary here, though I'm about to add them anyway. _[…short pause…]_ Actually, looking at the edit history, it was [caf](http://stackoverflow.com/users/134633/caf) who [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4491716/revisions) my answer to add the `sizeof` (which I'd managed to leave out) and that is why the parentheses are absent.

Comment: Well I am using C code in an iphone app and I used this code and it kept failing. I realized that it was the missing parenthesis. Maybe it's an iOS/OSX thing. When I was taking a networking class I did my coding in OSX (all in pure C), and I noticed that osx allowed you to do some funky stuff, but when I moved it to Linux to do my real tests it would fail.

Comment: I'd need to see your code to be able to explain why you ran into trouble, but `sizeof` is a high-precedence operator. I just double checked with: `#include <stdio.h>` then `int main(void) { char a[10]; printf("%zu\n", sizeof a[0]); printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a[0])); return 0; }` and it prints `1` twice as I'd expect. I normally put the parentheses in, but I've had raging disputes both on SO and in the office about whether to remember when parentheses are needed and when they aren't, or just to use parentheses all the time because it always works. I am firmly in the parentheses-all-the-time camp.

Comment: I'll have to retract my statement. I just did some more tests and realized it was something else (was calling free on the last element for some reason. I've been coding all day...don't ask lol) To confirm I removed the parenthesis again and it still works. You're right. Something new I just learned.

Comment: I tried many solutions, but at least for me, only this one worked. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

C arrays cannot be resized, so you cannot do this without creating a new array. Some suggestions you could implement:

1. Mark the item as deleted (lazy deletion) by either having a second `deleted` bool array or setting the item to some unused value such as -1.
2. Use vectors, but then this is not C anymore. STL vectors have an `erase()` method.
3. Vectors will be inefficient to delete from, so depending on the other operations you perform you could use a `deque`. Again, this then becomes C++, but you can also use `erase()` on a `deque`.

Comment: so I need to create another array and move the values from the original one to the new one?
Also I need to put 0 at the end of the array.

Comment: Your answer seems to be about C++, but the question is about C.

Comment: @binarylife If you want to shorten the array, yes.

Comment: @Jonathan If you read you will see that I explicitly mentioned this. Most beginners aren't aware of the difference between C and C++, so could easily tag the question as C when they meant C++.

Comment: Hmmm; I've seen plenty of C++ questions tagged C and C++ (and some C questions double-tagged), but I've not seen many C++ questions tagged just C, nor many C questions tagged C++.

Comment: But I am talking about C not C++. Also I think I should use pointers to point to the value .

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use a linked list, binary tree or other data structure that allows you to quickly search for and remove nodes containing the target data.

Comment: I am still a beginner , I don't know how to use linked list or data structure yet! thanks anyway