# Removing a string from an struct array in C

Tags: arrays, c, struct

My main focus is around "void deletion" and "int remove student". I am taking a gradebook of user input names, which if you test the display and addStudent functions they work fine, but i can not figure out how to remove a student from the gradebook. I am new to struct(and it is required to use them) so any help is appreciated. Included is my attempt at a deletion function, let me know where i went wrong. Thanks!

Also, I need a function that can update a students information post-insertion, so if there is an easy way to do that, it is valuable information.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>


typedef struct{

    char name[30];
    double havg;
    double qavg;
    double eavg;

}gradebook_t;


int addStudent(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents, int capacity);
int removeStudent(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents);
void updateStudent();
void displayStudents(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents);
void missingStudent();
void deletion(int num, int pos,char arr[]);


int main()
{
    gradebook_t classr[5];
    
    int capacity = 5;
    int currentstudents = 0;
    int selection;
    int x = 0;
    
    while(x == 0)
    {
        printf("Choose a selection:\n");
        printf("1. Add a student\n");
        printf("2. Display students\n");
        printf("3. Remove a student\n");
        printf("0. Exit\n");
        
        scanf("%d",&selection);
        
        if(selection == 1)
        {
            currentstudents += addStudent(classr,currentstudents,capacity);
        }
        else if(selection == 2)
        {
            displayStudents(classr, currentstudents);
        }
        else if(selection == 3)
        {
            currentstudents += removeStudent(classr, currentstudents);
        }
        else if(selection == 0)
        {
            x += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Not a selection, try again...\n");
            printf("curretnstudents = %d",currentstudents);
        }
    }
    


    return 0;
}


int addStudent(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents, int capacity)
{
    if(currentstudents != capacity)
    {
        printf("Enter a student name:");
        scanf("%s", classr[currentstudents].name);
        
        printf("Enter a homework average:");
        scanf("%lf", &classr[currentstudents].havg);
   
        printf("Enter a quiz average:");
        scanf("%lf", &classr[currentstudents].qavg);
   
        printf("Enter an exam average:");
        scanf("%lf", &classr[currentstudents].eavg);
   
    }
    else
    {
        printf("the shelf full");
    }
 
  //currentstudents += 1;
}


void displayStudents(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents)
{
    for(int index = 0; index < currentstudents; index++)
    {
        printf("Student %d Name : %s\n",index+1, classr[index].name);
        printf("Student %d HW AVG : %.2lf\n",index+1, classr[index].havg);
        printf("Student %d QUIZ AVG : %.2lf\n",index+1, classr[index].qavg);
        printf("Student %d EXAM AVG : %.2lf\n\n",index+1, classr[index].eavg);
    }
}

int removeStudent(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents)
{
    char find1[20];

    printf("Enter a student name:");
    scanf("%s",find1);
    
    int index = find(classr,find1);
    classr[index] = classr[currentstudents-1];
}

void deletion(int num, int pos, char arr[])
{
}
```

Comment: I think `removeStudent` should `return -1;` so that `currentstudents` gets deceremented. Also, `return 0;` when not found.

Comment: @001 True, I'll go ahead and add that as well.

Comment: `deletion` has a problem if `pos = 0`. In that case, `i` will be `-1` at the start of the loop. [How to remove an element found in an array and shift the array elements to the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4491625)

Comment: @001 I am looking through the link you sent, and I can't really tell where the information in the link can be applied, I'll edit it with my take on it.

Comment: @001 Edited, however I can't find the header that goes along with the find() function, algorithm.h and iostream.h don't work :/

Comment: What are `algorithm.h` and `iostream.h`? Are you using TurboC++?

Comment: @001 found the answer, thanks bro :D

Comment: @Jabberwocky disregard sire, I decided to ignore the find() function completely and just use a tradition for loop.

Comment: What happens if I type in 40 letters when you ask for the student name?

Comment: @gnasher729 the universe implodes and all that exists shall cease itself to the ripple of the void.

Answer (score 1):

Deletion function was redundant:

```
for(int index = 0; index < currentstudents; index++)
{
    if(strcmp(find1,classr[index].name) == 0)
    {
        classr[index] = classr[currentstudents-1];
    }
}
```

^This works.